# What is Caret Browsing mode in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Everyone talks about it, but I have no idea what it is. Could someone explain what is it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like when you were typing the question, it's the little blinking | symbol. Hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to turn it on, it'll let you more easily copy text with the keyboard, if that's your thing.

Comment: Well I never knew that...  useful.

Answer (score 5):

Caret Browsing lets you use standard navigation keys on your keyboard e.g. Home, End, Page Up, Page Down, and the arrow keys to move around within a webpage (just like you would move around in a word document), instead of using the mouse.

Comment: Also helps with selecting text.